# How to change the select tag option in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

The below html code has 2 different select tags with same options. If the user changes one of them i also want that the value in the other select tag also changes. I have a javascript function that does that but it is not working ?

```
function change(str) {
    document.getElementById("select-choice-direction-user")
        .selectedIndex = document.getElementById("select-choice-direction")
        .selectedIndex;
}

<select name="select-choice-direction" id="select-choice-direction" data-native-menu="false" onchange="change(this);">
    <option value="1">1 Blueridge-McKee GoLine</option>
    <option value="2">2 Bluejay-Huntingdon GoLine</option>
    <option value="3">3 Clearbrook-UFV GoLine</option>
    <option value="4">4 Saddle</option>
    <option value="5">5 Hospital</option>
    <option value="6">6 Gladwin-Peardonville</option>
</select>
<select name="select-choice-direction-user" id="select-choice-direction-user" data-native-menu="false" onchange="change(this);">
    <option value="1">1 Blueridge-McKee GoLine</option>
    <option value="2">2 Bluejay-Huntingdon GoLine</option>
    <option value="3">3 Clearbrook-UFV GoLine</option>
    <option value="4">4 Saddle</option>
    <option value="5">5 Hospital</option>
    <option value="6">6 Gladwin-Peardonville</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Different IDs:

```
<select name="select-choice-direction-user" id="select-choice-direction-user"
                                                                  No 'n'----^

document.getElementById("select-choice-direction-usern").selectedIndex =  
                                                     ^--- Has an 'n'
```

Comment: Considering the edit just made, this must not be present in the actual code.

Comment: @isherwood is right it is not present in the actual code